# Django respond to a search result in a database from navbar

Tags: django, database, search

I'm working on a django app that has a database with various posts. These posts have names and ids. The ids are in sub urls like sitename.com/1. On every page of the django app, I have a navbar which was extended from base.html. The navbar has a search bar which is really a form submission.

When I want to execute a search, I can take in the search data and use filters on it with the given database. However, the views.py has a function for each sub url. With each sub url that has a form on it, the function on views.py is handling the post request for the form.

How am I going to handle the requests from the search bar form? Do I have to make a function that handles it and then copy paste a call for that function at the beginning of the functions for every other page I want to make? Is there an easier way to do this? I've heard of using @ but I don't know if that is the right use for this sort of problem.

Comment: Without seeing any code, assuming I fully understand so correct me where needed, could you have the form action of the search bar direct to this view function that performs this filtering and then in that view function perform a redirect after to the view function for that particular url (that then handles the form data). But then this is basically just creating your own middleware which would be more robust. So that is probably the way to go.

Comment: Oh yeah. I should have thought of that. I can just have it redirect to a new page like you said. Thanks!